# Projecting EPSG:4326 with OpenLayers 2 and GeoJSON?

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, javascript, geojson

I'm trying to project some GeoJSON data but it ends up at `0,0`. I've looked at other posts and tried those solutions to no avail.

Can anyone help?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
    <script src="../lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
  <script defer='defer' type='text/javascript'>
    var featurecollection = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [15.87646484375, 44.1748046875]},
         properties": {"id": "1", "Tradnummer": "1", "Art": "Betula pendula" } 
    };    
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
      projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
    });    
    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Open Street Map");
    map.addLayer(layer);
    //map.zoomToMaxExtent();    
    var layerProj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var targetProj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
    var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
    var geojson = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
      projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
      format: OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON
    });    
    geojson.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(featurecollection));
    // Need to transform the features geometry here?
    var feature = geojson.features[0];
    var geometry = feature.geometry.clone();
    geometry.transform(layerProj, targetProj);    
    map.addLayer(geojson);    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22529/trouble-displaying-geojson-file-in-openlayers?rq=1).

Have amended my code to this:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {

  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
  units: "m",
  maxResolution: 156543.0339,
my      displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
      controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Scale(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
      ]
    });

var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Open Street Map");

var vectorlyr = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
  "test",{
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    url: 'json1.php',
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
      internalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
      externalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")})
    }),
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()]/*,
    styleMap: vector_style_map*/
});

map.addLayers([osm, vectorlyr]);

map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

// transform coordinates for centering the map and set zoom level
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(11.59, 57.43).transform(
  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
  map.getProjectionObject()
), 4);
```

Hope this helps someone else :)