# Help with vector layer (geojson) in openlayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geojson, vector-layer

> In openlayers I try get geojson from geoserver to overlay in map. Code:

```
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
})
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=global:ua46lo_hydran_poi&SRS=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson",
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
    success:function(data){
        // If response is valid
        var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        console.log(data);
        // reads and converts GeoJSon to Feature Object
        var features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures(data);
        vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
    }
});
var restaurantsold = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'b_layer',
    source : vectorSource
});
```

Add this layer to map, but get only this:
[image]

Why?
geojson from geoserver:

```
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "totalFeatures": 2450,
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "ua46lo_hydran_poi.1",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          24.068626,
          49.785831
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "gid": 1,
        "mp_type": "0x5000",
        "label": "Антонича Б. вул., 6",
        "indicator": "Так",
        "typnet": "К",
        "dsitky": "200",
        "typpg": "М"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "ua46lo_hydran_poi.2",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          24.069041,
          49.785097
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "gid": 2,
        "mp_type": "0x5000",
        "label": "Антонича Б. вул., 12",
        "indicator": "Так",
        "typnet": "К",
        "dsitky": "600",
        "typpg": "М"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "ua46lo_hydran_poi.3",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          24.068407,
          49.783316
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "gid": 3,
        "mp_type": "0x5000",
        "label": "Антонича Б. вул., 24",
        "indicator": "Так",
        "typnet": "К",
        "dsitky": "600",
        "typpg": "М"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "ua46lo_hydran_poi.4",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          24.067433,
          49.783146
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "gid": 4,
        "mp_type": "0x5000",
        "label": "Антонича Б. вул., 26",
        "indicator": "Так",
        "typnet": "К",
        "dsitky": "250",
        "typpg": "М"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "ua46lo_hydran_poi.5",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          24.060515,
          49.791894
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "gid": 5,
        "mp_type": "0x5000",
        "label": "Антоненка-Давидовича Б. вул., 1",
        "indicator": "Так",
        "typnet": "К",
        "dsitky": "250",
        "typpg": "М"
      }
    }
  ],
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is in Web Mercator projection (EPSG:3857) and your data in Lat/Lon (EPSG:4326) as all GeoJSON is (see the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946)). Therefore your data ends up near Null Island (or 0,0).

The solution is simple [transform your data to EPSG:3857](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118762/reproject-geojson-in-openlayers-3) before adding it to the map.